# Drawable + Background Color on ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout like this

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am filling all these `ImageViews` with different colors on run time using

```
view.setBackgroundColor()
```

When I set a drawable with rounded corners on the parent LinearLayout, it doesn't show up. Probably because I am setting background colors to ImageViews. How can I achieve that? 
O/P should a rectangle with rounded corners containing three `ImageViews`.

Comment: Provide more information about your layout and the source code plz

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add padding to your `LinearLayout`. Make sure the padding is equal to the stroke width of your `drawable` for the border of the rounded rectangle to be visible

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#076"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#406"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#e70"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the rounded_rect.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="9dp" />

    <stroke
        android:color="#F00"
        android:width="3dp" />

    <solid android:color="#4F00" />

</shape>
```